# How to stop Jquery click stop calling server call if there is any client side error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have the below button on click function it is validating the client side textbox. But after rendering the validation errors it goes into the server call. I want to stop the server call. If there is any validation errors in the client side.

I used preventDefault and return false but nothing is working in my case.

Cshtml :

```
<div>

    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Feedback" method="post" asp-area="Patient.Feedback" id="feedback" class="u-pb">
        @Html.AntiForgeryTokenOrchard()
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Your feedback was not submitted:")

        <div class="feedback-container feedback-error feedback-entry feedback-content feedback-other feedback-clinical feedback-freelance u-mb">
            <div id="errorurldiv" class="fieldcontain">
                <div class="field field--full col--medium-8 field--text">
                    <div class="feedback-container feedback-error">
                        <label class="field__label" for="link">Link to the page where you found the error</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("link", (string)Model.Link, new { @class = "page-link field__input field__input--text" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="feedback-container feedback-clinical">
                        <div class="clinicallink">
                            <label class="field__label" for="clinicalcontentlink">Link to the page you want to provide feedback for</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("clinicalcontentlink", (string)Model.ClinicalContentLink, new { @class = "page-link field__input field__input--text" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field fieldcontain feedback-container feedback-clinical feedback-error feedback-entry feedback-content feedback-other">
                <label class="field__label" for="profession">Are you a Health Professional?</label>
                <div class="fieldGroup__fields fieldGroup__fields--horizontal">
                    <div class="field field--radio">
                        <input class="field__input field__input--radio" id="yes" type="radio" name="profession" value="Heath Professional" @(Model.Profession == "Heath Professional" ? "checked" : string.Empty)>
                        <label class="field__label" for="yes">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field field--radio">
                        <input class="field__input field__input--radio" id="no" type="radio" name="profession" value="Patient" @(Model.Profession == "Patient" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Profession) ? "checked" : string.Empty)>
                        <label class="field__label" for="no">No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            @Display.Parts_Recaptcha()
            <input type="button" id="btn-submit" class="g-recaptcha button u-mt--s ui-kit-button-medium" data-sitekey="6LeFbiUUAAAAANuXwwXtMkpw_5vgJ3vo8NlsYdNw" data-callback="rcCallback" value="Send feedback"><span class="button__text">Send Feedback</span></input>
        </div>
      
    </form>
</div>
```

Client Jquery :

```
$("#btn-submit").on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const validationerrors = document.createElement('div');
    const form = document.getElementById("feedback");

    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    const span = document.createElement('span')

    validationerrors.className = "validation-summary-errors";

    var validation = [];

    const emailValue = $('#email').val();
    const name = $('#Name').val();
    const Comment = $('#Comment').val();
    const aboutyourself = $('#AboutYourself').val();
    const country = $('#country').val();

    if (name === "") {
        validation.push("Your name is required");
    }
    if (Comment === "") {
        validation.push("Your feedback is required");
    }
    if (aboutyourself === "") {
        validation.push("Your aboutyourself is required");
    }
    if (emailValue === "") {
        validation.push("Your email address is required");
    }
    else if (!validateEmail(emailValue)) {
        validation.push("Invalid Email Address");
    }
    if (country === "") {
        validation.push("Your country is required");
    }
    
    if (validation.length > 0) {
        span.append('Your feedback was not submitted:');
        validationerrors.append(span);

        for (var i = 0; i < validation.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(validation[i]));
            ul.appendChild(item);
        }

        validationerrors.append(ul);
        form.prepend(validationerrors);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I also tried submit function for the form as the below case. It stops working after first button click. Like on first click it render the client validation errors and after correcting the input the button is not even triggering anything.

```
$("#feedback").submit(function (e) {});
```

Comment: Change type of btn to submit and use $("#feedback").submit(function (e) {});  + preventDefault

Comment: @mostafakhoramnia Where should i place the preventDefault at the end of submit or after the whole submit completes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,`<input type="button">` will not submit the form when clicking it.If you want to  submit the form when `validation.length == 0`.You can use `$("#feedback").submit();`.Here is a demo:

```
$("#btn-submit").on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const validationerrors = document.createElement('div');
    const form = document.getElementById("feedback");

    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    const span = document.createElement('span')

    validationerrors.className = "validation-summary-errors";

    var validation = [];

    const emailValue = $('#email').val();
    const name = $('#Name').val();
    const Comment = $('#Comment').val();
    const aboutyourself = $('#AboutYourself').val();
    const country = $('#country').val();

    if (name === "") {
        validation.push("Your name is required");
    }
    if (Comment === "") {
        validation.push("Your feedback is required");
    }
    if (aboutyourself === "") {
        validation.push("Your aboutyourself is required");
    }
    if (emailValue === "") {
        validation.push("Your email address is required");
    }
    else if (!validateEmail(emailValue)) {
        validation.push("Invalid Email Address");
    }
    if (country === "") {
        validation.push("Your country is required");
    }
    
    if (validation.length > 0) {
        span.append('Your feedback was not submitted:');
        validationerrors.append(span);

        for (var i = 0; i < validation.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(validation[i]));
            ul.appendChild(item);
        }

        validationerrors.append(ul);
        form.prepend(validationerrors);
        return false;
    }else{
        $("#feedback").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue is after performing client validation the browser is not stopping it is making the server call. return false is not preventing my application to stop, it goes into the next step i.e, making server call.

Comment: The if condition itself should fail because of return false but it is making server call and I get another round of validation message from the server.

Comment: I test with `<input type="button">`,and it will not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you have added `$("#feedback").submit(function (e) {});` to your code - this will prevent ANY form submission from happening.

Building off Yiyi/mostafa's answers:

Change the `input` `type="button"` to a `button` element with `type="submit"` - this will make the form submit when it is clicked.

ALSO:
Change `$("#btn-submit").on('click'` to `$("#feedback").on('submit'` - instead of clicking the button and validating, we will allow the validation to happen when we submit the form.

THEN at the end, you STILL keep the `return false` (it won't submit) but change `$("#feedback").submit();` to `return true` so the form will submit.

Example HTML:

```html
<button type="submit">Send Feedback</button>
```

Example JavaScript:

```js
// we get the form by ID and watch the submit function
const $form = $("#feedback"); // get the form

$form.on('submit',function (e) {
    // WE ARE NOT PREVENTING DEFAULT YET

    // we do not need to build out our validation elements because we may not need them

    let validation = []; // hold our error messages

    const emailValue = $('#email').val();
    const name = $('#Name').val();
    const Comment = $('#Comment').val();
    const aboutyourself = $('#AboutYourself').val();
    const country = $('#country').val();

    if (name === "") {
        validation.push("Your name is required");
    }
    if (Comment === "") {
        validation.push("Your feedback is required");
    }
    if (aboutyourself === "") {
        validation.push("Your aboutyourself is required");
    }
    if (emailValue === "") {
        validation.push("Your email address is required");
    }
    else if (!validateEmail(emailValue)) {
        validation.push("Invalid Email Address");
    }
    if (country === "") {
        validation.push("Your country is required");
    }
    
    if (validation.length > 0) {
        // build out our validation
        const validationerrors = document.createElement('div');
        validationerrors.className = "validation-summary-errors";
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        const span = document.createElement('span')

        span.append('Your feedback was not submitted:');
        validationerrors.append(span);

        for (var i = 0; i < validation.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(validation[i]));
            ul.appendChild(item);
        }

        validationerrors.append(ul);
        // we already have jQuery grabbing our form, let's use it
        $form.prepend(validationerrors);

        // prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        // no errors, submit form
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:
1 : Input type submit

2 :

```
$("#feedback").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $form = $(this);
const validationerrors = document.createElement('div');
const form = document.getElementById("feedback");

const ul = document.createElement('ul');
const span = document.createElement('span')

validationerrors.className = "validation-summary-errors";

var validation = [];

const emailValue = $('#email').val();
const name = $('#Name').val();
const Comment = $('#Comment').val();
const aboutyourself = $('#AboutYourself').val();
const country = $('#country').val();

if (name === "") {
    validation.push("Your name is required");
}
if (Comment === "") {
    validation.push("Your feedback is required");
}
if (aboutyourself === "") {
    validation.push("Your aboutyourself is required");
}
if (emailValue === "") {
    validation.push("Your email address is required");
}
else if (!validateEmail(emailValue)) {
    validation.push("Invalid Email Address");
}
if (country === "") {
    validation.push("Your country is required");
}

if (validation.length > 0) {
    span.append('Your feedback was not submitted:');
    validationerrors.append(span);

    for (var i = 0; i < validation.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(validation[i]));
        ul.appendChild(item);
    }

    validationerrors.append(ul);
    form.prepend(validationerrors);
    return false;
}else{
    $.post(
$form.attr(URL),
$form.serialize());
}
});
```